# Start paragraphs on same height regardless of headline-height

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I've been researching and trying for ages now and it kind of drives me crazy, that I am not able to solve this seemingly simple problem.

I've been trying to fit headings in blogpost-previews to the same height using flexbox. If a heading is "too long" it gets a line-break and has a greater height than the shorter ones, which is okay. However, the paragraph below the heading don't start on the same height anymore, which just looks very odd. Is there a simple way to achieve this, preferably with flexbox?

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is a link to the [code on codepen](http://codepen.io/Kritzzz/pen/rrppqE)

```
<div class="blogpost-container">

  <div class="blogpost">

    <header class="blogpost__header">
      <div class="dummy-image"></div>
      <a href="#"><h1>Blogpost heading short</h1></a>
    </header>

    <div class="blogpost__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Graecum enim hunc versum nostis omnes: Suavis laborum est praeteritorum memoria. 
      Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="blogpost">

    <header class="blogpost__header">
      <div class="dummy-image"></div>
      <a href="#"><h1>Blogpost Heading is longer and thus has a greater height than the short one</h1></a>
    </header>

    <div class="blogpost__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Graecum enim hunc versum nostis omnes: Suavis laborum est praeteritorum memoria. 
      Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4sew4x2m/

I used `<table>`. But you can use `display:table` instead.

From my point of view, if you you flex, you have to give width for that divs. In case of using tables, you don't have to- that's the advantage.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, that does work indeed. It seems like more of a workaround though, are you certain there's not a non-table solution to this? I know I could probably do this with JS, but I was looking for neat, clean CSS version to make it work :). Thanks again!